# conditional section syntaxe with razor asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm not really familiar with the razor view engine. So, i have a problem with the syntaxe.

I have "_layout.cshtml" :

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Slideshow"))
{
     @RenderSection("Slideshow");
}
else
{
     <p>blah blah blah</p>
}
```

And then, in the "default.cshtml"

```
@if(@ViewBag.Article == null)
{
    <p>blabla</p>
}
else
{
    @section Slideshow
    {
        <ul><li>slide here</li></ul>
    }
}
```

So, here is my problem :
If i let the @ before section, i have an error [line:27] telling me that i don't have to keep the @ inside a @if statement :

```
"Mot clé "section" inattendu après le caractère "@". Une fois à l'intérieur du code,
vous n'avez pas besoin de préfixer des constructions telles que "section" avec "@"."
```

If i don't let the @ before section, i have an error[line:29] 2 lines after (

...) telling me a } is missing.

```
CS1513: } attendue
```

So, i guess it is possible to do but i don't know how to do it. Could you help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should compile:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Slideshow"))
{
     RenderSection("Slideshow");
}
else
{
    @:<p>blah blah blah</p>
}


@if(ViewBag.Article == null)
{
    @:<p>blabla</p>
}
else
{
    section Slideshow
    {
        @:<ul><li>slide here</li></ul>
    }
}
```

You need to start a c# statement with a @ only if the compiler doesn't know you want to write actual code.

Using @: at the start of plain text, the compiler knows its plain text.

Using `<text></text>` tags to enclose text has the same effect. Every c# statement inside `</text>` tag needs to start with a @

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
 @{
    if(ViewBag.Article == null)
{
    <p>blabla</p>
}
else
{
    section Slideshow
    {
        <ul><li>slide here</li></ul>
    }
}    
    }
```